# Can MongoDB Change Events be considered unique?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, changestream

### Description

I am utilizing the MongoDb change stream (C# MongoDB.Driver v2.12.0) to track changes on a single collection.
In an experimental use case the collection stores information about execution of threads.

A thread has two properties:

- `Status` - RUNNING, BLOCKED or COMPLETED
- `BlockedCount` - number of blocking threads

During its execution, a thread can spawn children threads and be blocked until all of the children are not completed. Whenever a children thread completes its execution, it updates the database by decrementing the `BlockedCount` of the parent. Once the `BlockedCount` drops to 0, the parent thread should continue its execution.

Code for subscribing to change stream:

```
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<T>>()
                    .Match(change => change.OperationType == ChangeStreamOperationType.Insert ||
                                     change.OperationType == ChangeStreamOperationType.Update ||
                                     change.OperationType == ChangeStreamOperationType.Replace)
                    .AppendStage<ChangeStreamDocument<T>, ChangeStreamDocument<T>, ChangeStreamOutputWrapper<T>>(
                                     "{ $project: { '_id': 1, 'fullDocument': 1, 'ns': 1, 'documentKey': 1 }}");

var options = new ChangeStreamOptions
{
    FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup
};

using (var cursor = await coll.WatchAsync(pipeline, options, cancellationToken))
{
    await cursor.ForEachAsync(async change =>
    {
        // await some handler routine
    }, cancellationToken);
}
```

### Issue

What I have noticed is that the change events can be different even if the update operations are exactly the same.
To better explain this, here is an example:

There is 1 parent thread and 3 children threads completing their execution, there are two different behaviors observed:

- 3 distinct update events for the parent thread:

  - "Status" : "BLOCKED", "BlockedCount" : 2
  - "Status" : "BLOCKED", "BlockedCount" : 1
  - "Status" : "BLOCKED", "BlockedCount" : 0
- 3 identical update events for the parent thread:

  - "Status" : "BLOCKED", "BlockedCount" : 0
  - "Status" : "BLOCKED", "BlockedCount" : 0
  - "Status" : "BLOCKED", "BlockedCount" : 0

### Questions

1. Is this considered a normal behavior?
2. Is there some kind of configuration that would prevent this, and fire only the 'latest' update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the expected behavior. The documentation ([link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#update-event)) states, that:

> The `fullDocument` document represents the most current majority-committed version of the updated document. The `fullDocument` document may vary from the document at the time of the update operation depending on the number of interleaving majority-committed operations that occur between the update operation and the document lookup.

And as far as I know, there's no way to overcome nor adjust this behavior. However, what you *can* do, is to read `updateDescription` directly, manually tracking the changes. It's not going to be complex if the `BlockedCount` is only being set (i.e., not removed and re-added later).